# Mathematical Reasoning In Physics

Tags: newtonian-gravity, terminology, dimensional-analysis, mathematics, scaling

Does this form of reasoning have a name. I often see it but am a little confused on how to read/understand it and  wanted to look more into it but don't know what to call it

Ex.
Let's call the force law between the objects $F(m_1,m_2,r)$. We know that if we put the body $m_1$ in free fall, the acceleration doesn't depend on the mass, so

$$F(m_1,m_2,r)=m_1G(m_2,r)$$
So that the mass will cancel in Newton's law to give a universal acceleration. This gives you the relation

$$F(\lambda m_1,m_2,r)=\lambda F(m_1,m_2,r).$$

Source: [Combining Proportions to get Newton's Law of Universal Gravitation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32719/)

Comment: Are you asking whether there is a name for mathematical reasoning in general (based on the title of the question), or specifically a name for the type of scaling argument you give in your example?

Comment: A function with this property is called homogeneous. In this case homogeneous of degree 1. If that's what your asking

Comment: This is not exactly the case, but dimensional analysis helps you to check the soundness of mathematical relations between physical quantities.

Comment: What you've learned in mathematics classes applies to physics classes as well. I am not familiar with any new version of math named for use in physics or engineering

Comment: There's no use in the inference$$F(m_1,\,m_2,\,r)=m_1G(m_2,\,r)\implies F(\lambda m_1,\,m_2,\,r)=\lambda F(m_1,\,m_2,\,r)$$alone. The linked source uses the second mass in a similar way to show$$F(m_1,\,m_2,\,r)=m_1m_2F(1,\,1,\,r).$$It's probably worth asking about the whole argument.

Comment: This property of a mathematical object is invariance with an operation or set of operations. Here, the object "F(parameters)" is invariant with "changes in m1, m2 such that m1m2 is constant".